# Alt and Control keys aren't responding

Tags: windows, keyboard

My <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys don't respond when pressed.

Also, when trying to use Windows Explorer, the explorer will select a file with alphabet character or number when pressing a key.  For example:  Open File Explorer, press a key, then it navigates to a file.

Copy, Paste, and Cut functions do not work, due to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> not functioning.

Pressing a key on the keyboard when the "On-Screen Keyboard" is displayed should "flash" that key.  However, pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys while viewing the On-Screen Keyboard show the keys not responding.

I've tried troubleshooting by:

- Using another keyboard, but that results in the same issue.  <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> don't function, but all other keys do.
- Restarting the Computer, but the issue still persists

How do I get the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys to work again without factory resetting my PC?  The problem started this morning, but I don't know what triggered it as my PC was idle at the time.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.